# How to display certain buffers below the selected window?

Tags: display-buffer-alist

For now I can open *Help* buffer below current one by splitting its window using regex

```
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
             '("^\\*.*\\*$" . (display-buffer-below-selected)))
```

How can I make it so that the same behaviour applies to `*shell*` and `*man*` to name a few.

UPDATE: opening through command works for `*shell*` but if I have multiple shells in switch buffer is there streamlined way to temporarily open them?

Comment: What does `C-h v display-buffer-alist` tell you?

Comment: how would I apply the same behaviour when opening from switch-buffer, C-x b?

Comment: `popwin` package works fine but I found out that I don't really this behaviour since I sometimes still need to view buffers while switching